# How to better organize the code in C++ projects

Tags: c++, namespaces, code-organization

I'm currently in the process of trying to organize my code in better way.

To do that I used namespaces, grouping classes by components, each having a defined role and a few interfaces (actually Abstract classes).

I found it to be pretty good, especially when I had to rewrite an entire component and I did with almost no impact on the others. (I believe it would have been a lot more difficult with a bunch of mixed-up classes and methods)

Yet I'm not 100% happy with it. Especially I'd like to do a better separation between interfaces, the public face of the components, and their implementations in behind. 
I think the 'interface' of the component itself should be clearer, I mean a new comer should understand easily what interfaces he must implement, what interfaces he can use and what's part of the implementation.

Soon I'll start a bigger project involving up to 5 devs, and I'd like to be clear in my mind on that point.

So what about you? how do you do it? how do you organize your code?

Comment: Just stealthily changing the question and thus invalidating answers is unfair ;)

Comment: sorry I just re-read it and thought it wasn't that good :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Especially I'd like to do a better
>   separation between interfaces, the
>   public face of the components, and
>   their implementations in behind.

I think what you're looking for is the [Facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) pattern:

> A facade is an object that provides a simplified interface to a larger body of code, such as a class library. -- Wikipedia

You may also want to look at the [Mediator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) and [Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) patterns if you have complex interactions in your classes.

The [Pimpl](http://gotw.ca/gotw/024.htm) idiom (aka compiler firewall) is also useful for hiding implementation details and reducing build times. I prefer to use Pimpl over interface classes + factories when I don't need polymorphism. Be careful not to over-use it though. Don't use Pimpl for lightweight types that are normally allocated on the stack (like a 3D point or complex number). Use it for the bigger, longer-lived classes that have dependencies on other classes/libraries that you'd wish to hide from the user.

In large-scale projects, it's important to not use an #include directives in a header file when a simple forward declaration will do. Only put an #include directives in a header file if absolutely necessary (prefer to put #includes in the implementation files). If done right, proper #include discipline will reduce your compile times significantly. The Pimpl idiom can help to move #includes from header files to their corresponding implementation files.

A coherent collection of classes / functions can be grouped together in it's own namespace and put in a subdirectory of your source tree (the subdirectory should have the same name as the library namespace). You can then create a static library subproject/makefile for that package and link it with your main application. This is what I'd consider a "package" in UML jargon. In an ideal package, classes are closely related to each other, but loosely related with classes outside the package. It is helpful to draw dependency diagrams of your packages to make sure there are no cyclical dependencies.

Comment: About the #include directives, that's 'funny', at work I have to follow a code convention which specifies exactly the opposite ... even though I was used to do foward declaration.

Comment: You can tell them that even Google encourages forward declarations: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml?showone=Header_File_Dependencies#Header_File_Dependencies

Comment: Google appears to have changed their mind!
"Avoid using forward declarations where possible. Instead, #include the headers you need."
[Here](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Forward_Declarations)

Answer (score 4):

There are two common approaches:

If, apart from the public interface, you only need some helper functions, just put them in an unnamed namespace in the implementation file:

```
// header:

class MyClass {
// interface etc.
};

// source file:

namespace {
    void someHelper() {}
}

// ... MyClass implementation
```

If you find yourself wanting to hide member functions, consider using the PIMPL idiom:

```
class MyClassImpl; // forward declaration

class MyClass {
public:
    // public interface
private:
    MyClassImpl* pimpl;
};
```

`MyClassImpl` implements the functionality, while `MyClass` forwards calls to the public interface to the private implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You might find some of the suggestions in [Large Scale C++ Software Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633620) useful.  It's a bit dated (published in 1996) but still valuable, with pointers on structuring code to minimize the "recompiling the world when a single header file changes" problem.

Answer (score 0):

Herb Sutter's article on "[What's In a Class? - The Interface Principle](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill02.htm)" presents some ideas that many don't seem to think of when designing interfaces.  It's a bit dated (1998) but there's some useful stuff in there, nonetheless.

Answer (score -6):

First declare you variables you may use them in one string declaration also like so.

```
 char Name[100],Name2[100],Name3[100];
 using namespace std;
int main(){

 }
```

and if you have a long peice of code that could be used out of the program make it a new function.
likeso.

```
void Return(char Word[100]){
cout<<Word; 
cin.ignore();    
} 
int main(){ 
Return("Hello");
}
```

And I suggest any outside functions and declarations you put into a header file and link it
likeso
Dev-C++ #include "Resource.h"